# Add multilevel items to a unordered list using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

i need to build nested unorder list using below json object, each json object have id and parent id, root or top element parent id is 0

```
 JSON Object 

{
   "menu": [
         {"id":1,"name":"Dashboard","parent":0},
         {"id":2,"name":"Dashboard1","parent":0 },
         {"id":3,"name":"Dashboard2","parent":0},
         {"id":4,"name":"Dashboard3","parent":0},
         {"id":5,"name":"Dashboard4","parent":1},
         {"id":6,"name":"Dashboard5","parent":1},
         {"id":7,"name":"Dashboard6","parent":1},
         {"id":8,"name":"Dashboard7","parent":2},
         {"id":9,"name":"Dashboard8","parent":5}
          ]

}
```

Expected Result :

```
<ul class="menu" >
    <li >Dashboard</li>
    <li >Dashboard1
        <ul>
            <li> Dashboard4</li>
            <li> Dashboard5
                <ul>
                    <li> Dashboard8</li>                                                
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> Dashboard6</li>                            
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li >Dashboard2
        <ul>
            <li> Dashboard7</li>                                                
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li >Dashboard3</li>                
</ul>
```

i tried

```
 menuArr=[];
  $.each(menu,function(i,val){
     var parent=$(".menu");
     if(val.parent!=0){
        parent= menuArr[val.parent];
     }
     menuLi= $('<li>'+val.name+'</li>');
     parent.append(menuli);
     menuArr[val.id]=menuli;

  });
```

Comment: Cool, what have you tried? What problems did you come across?

Comment: reading this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692538/generate-unordered-list-from-json-data

Comment: Have you looked into any client-side templating like [Mustache.js](http://mustache.github.io/) or [ICanHaz](http://icanhazjs.com/)?

Comment: @KevinB see my tried sample code above

Comment: I'm sorry... hummm... why so many downvotes?

Comment: @coma: I'm guessing most of the downvotes came before he added in his sample code, when it just had input and expected result.

Comment: This question is really good an I had a nice time figuring it out, thanks. Downvoters are getting faster every day.

Comment: @coma thanks coma ,my question is very clear ,i don't know why my question is not a real question,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/LCFH5/2/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {

    var data = {
        "menu": [
            {"id":5,"name":"Dashboard4","parent":1},
            {"id":1,"name":"Dashboard","parent":0},
            {"id":2,"name":"Dashboard1","parent":0 },
            {"id":3,"name":"Dashboard2","parent":0},
            {"id":4,"name":"Dashboard3","parent":0},
            {"id":6,"name":"Dashboard5","parent":1},
            {"id":7,"name":"Dashboard6","parent":1},
            {"id":8,"name":"Dashboard7","parent":2},
            {"id":9,"name":"Dashboard8","parent":5}
        ]
    };

    var ul = $('#menu');
    var items = data.menu;
    var add = function(item) {

        var parent;

        if(item.parent > 0) {

            parent = ul.find('#n' + item.parent + ' > ul');

            if(parent.length < 1) {

                $.each(items, function(i) {

                    if(this.id === item.parent) {

                        parent = add(items.splice(i, 1)[0]);

                        return false;

                    }

                });

            }

        } else {

            parent = ul;

        }

        return parent.append('<li id="n' + item.id + '">' + item.name + '<ul></ul></li>');

    };

    while(items.length > 0) {

        add(items.shift());

    }

});
```

It's more clear and takes care about unsorted data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-  http://jsfiddle.net/ngRns/

```
  var root;
for (var key in json) {
    root = key;
    break
}
var ul = $('<ul>',{'class':key,'data-level':0});

var prev = undefined;
$.each(json[root], function (_, obj) {
    if (prev && obj.parent > prev.parent) {
        ('[data-level=' + prev.parent + ']', ul).find('li:last').append($('<ul data-level=' + obj.parent + '>'));
    }
    ul.find('[data-level=' + obj.parent + ']').andSelf().last().append($('<li>', {
        text: obj.name
    }));
    prev = obj;
});
```

**Update**  http://jsfiddle.net/XAcqf/

var ul = $('', {
    'class': key
});

```
$.each(json[root], function (_, obj) {
    var li = ul.find('li#' + obj.parent);
    if (li.length != 0) {
        li.last().append($('<ul>').append($('<li>', {
            text: obj.name,
            id: obj.id
        })));;
    } else {
        ul.append($('<li>', {
            text: obj.name,
            id: obj.id
        }));
    }

});
```

Comment: child element is appending to wrong parent element

Comment: OK i thought about level... Check this now.. I have uipdated

Comment: but we don't want all child node start with <ul> ,see my expected result

Comment: ok Check this http://jsfiddle.net/rxTr3/

Answer (score 1):

with this markup to start:

```
<ul class="menu"></ul>
```

and this (I put the JSON in an object as I do not know your source:

```
var myj = {
    "menu": [{
        "id": 1,
            "name": "Dashboard",
            "parent": 0
    }, {
        "id": 2,
            "name": "Dashboard1",
            "parent": 0
    }, {
        "id": 3,
            "name": "Dashboard2",
            "parent": 0
    }, {
        "id": 4,
            "name": "Dashboard3",
            "parent": 0
    }, {
        "id": 5,
            "name": "Dashboard4",
            "parent": 1
    }, {
        "id": 6,
            "name": "Dashboard5",
            "parent": 1
    }, {
        "id": 7,
            "name": "Dashboard6",
            "parent": 1
    }, {
        "id": 8,
            "name": "Dashboard7",
            "parent": 2
    }, {
        "id": 9,
            "name": "Dashboard8",
            "parent": 5
    }]
};
```

I used this code:

```
menuArr = [];
$.each(myj.menu, function (i, val) {
    var menuLi
    var parent = $(".menu");
    if (val.parent != 0) {
        parent = menuArr[val.parent];
    }
    menuLi = $('<li>' + val.name + '</li>');
    parent.append(menuLi);
    menuArr[val.id] = menuLi;
});
```

Issues found:

- no object for the data (JSON)...not a big deal
- Your menuLi was menuli in some places

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xnfQk/