# How to get the JSON data to ul list using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to get the below json data to an unordered list using javascript and jquery

```
 var dataSource = ({
        "Items": ({
               "Juice": ({
                "Mango": "Mango",
                "Berry": "Berry",
                "Grapes": "Grapes",
                "Wine": ({
                    "Rose": "Rose",
                    "Red wine": "Red",
                    "Apple": "Apple",
                    "Hard drinks": ({
                        "Royal challenge": "Royal challenge",
                        "Blender's Pride": "Blender's Pride"
                    })
                })
            })

        })
    });
```

Comment: what data are you putting in a list?pls give more details

Comment: this is not a valid json!

Answer (score -1):

The Question is already answered in stack overflow. Kindly follow the below link.

[Generate unordered list from JSON Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692538/generate-unordered-list-from-json-data)

Cheers,
Sanjay