# Writing from JSON to HTML via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

Okay so I have a website that needs to display some data from a JSON file. The file contains different places in Norway with their name (Halden), state number (kommunenummer), number of men (menn) and number of women (kvinner).

I need to write some code that displays every name, state number and the total population of that place (which is the most recent measurement of men + women)

The JSON data looks like this:

```
"elementer": {
    "Halden": {
      "kommunenummer": "0101",
      "Menn": {
        "2016": 15306,
        "2017": 15473,
        "2018": 15620
      },
      "Kvinner": {
        "2016": 15238,
        "2017": 15317,
        "2018": 15417
      }
    }
```

And so on... The JSON file has a lot of these. The attribute "elementer" is where all the data is stored, so when I open "elementer" in my browser console, I get all of the states listed.

So this is where I need the JSON data to be displayed;

```
<div id="visOversikt">
  <ul>
    <li>hei</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
function load(url, objekt){

var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

request.open('GET', url, true)

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    console.log("Data er lastet inn vellykket...");
  }
}

request.onload = function() {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  objekt.data = JSON.parse(this.response)


}

request.send()

}

var befolkning = {


}

load("http://wildboy.uib.no/~tpe056/folk/104857.json", befolkning)


function getNames(data) {
  for (var variable in data) {
    console.log(variable)
  }



function displayOversikt() {
  }
}
```

The function `displayOversikt()` is where I thought I could write the code to display the data. If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Say I write getNames(befolkning.data.elementer) in the console, I listed all the state names (if it is of any help).

Comment: share final output mock layout ?

Comment: Is there any particular node you want to display in your li or you need to display all the data from json?

Comment: I need all the data to be displayed.

http://wildboy.uib.no/~tpe056/folk/104857.json

This is where the JSON data comes from. And I need to display all the names in it, like "Halden", "Moss", as you can see in it. As well, I need to display the "kommunenummer", and the population ("menn" + "kvinner")

So it should look like this:
"Halden, 0101, 31037"
"Moss, 0104, xxxxx"
Or something like that.

Comment: under "Menn" we have lot of year. so u need to show in ui li?

Comment: yes there is many years, but we just need the last year. so 2018 + women 2018

Comment: If you haven't already you should consider using one of the web application frameworks such as Angular or React, mapping data to HTML is what they do

Comment: By the way, I was told by my teacher to look up "document.createElement", which would be useful here. but I can't figure it out

Comment: First thing you need to do is look at what data you have and how it is organised. Then decide how you want to present it -- maybe a number of rows per area and what is in each? Then you need to work out how to transform the data from its current organisation to your target for display (maybe using a diagram and/or pseudo code). You can then initially code up output to the console. Finally, the last part, creating all those tricky elements, and formatting. P.S. this is straight-forward in html/js, I doubt your teacher wants you to learn angular!

Comment: Given you were told to use document.createElement yo should do as you are told! createElement does exactly that, it creates an element for you. It DOES NOT place it in the DOM tree, you have to do that yourself by appending to a tag already there e.g. <body> or another one that you place in the html e.g. <div id="my-answer">. See the w3school for how to do this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp. It will get you started and has everything that you need.

Comment: @lamalama69 You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score 0):

try to use [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) and split data and view

```js
let data = {"elementer":{"Halden":{"kommunenummer":"0101","Menn":{"2016":15306,"2017":15473,"2018":15620},"Kvinner":{"2016":15238,"2017":15317,"2018":15417}},"Moss":{"kommunenummer":"0104","Menn":{"2016":16000,"2017":16085,"2018":16124},"Kvinner":{"2016":16182,"2017":16322,"2018":16464}}}}

function displayOversikt(data) { 
  let inject = (s,o)=>s.replace(/\${(.*?)}/g,(x,g)=>o[g]); // helper which inject object fields into string in ${filedname}

  // Prepare data 
  let dd= Object.entries(data.elementer).map(([x, y]) => {
    let year = Object.keys(y.Menn).sort((a,b)=>+b-a)[0]; // last year
    return {
      population: y.Menn[year] + y.Kvinner[year],
      num: y.kommunenummer,
      name: x,
  }});
 
  // Read templae string
  let t=item.innerHTML;

  // Bind data to template and write in content element
  content.innerHTML = dd.map(x=>  inject(t,x)).join('');
}

displayOversikt(data);
```

```html
<div ><ul id="content"></ul></div>

<template id="item">
  <li>${name}, ${num}, ${population}</li>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in simple jquery.

Your html

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="JsonView.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="visOversikt">
    <ul></ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Your jquery(JsonView.js) would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON("http://wildboy.uib.no/~tpe056/folk/104857.json", function(json) {
        $.each(json['elementer'],function(key,value){
           var stateName        = key;
           var kommunenummer    = value['kommunenummer'];
           var MennValue        = value['Menn']['2018'];
           var FemaleValue      = value['Kvinner']['2018'];
           var addition         = MennValue + FemaleValue;
           var li               = '<li>'+stateName+', '+kommunenummer+', '+addition+'</li>'
           $("#visOversikt ul").append(li)
       });
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest looking at the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).  It's a real improvement on the older AJAX style you use.

Then, I would break the problem down into three phases:

- Use `fetch` to get the data
- Restructure the data to include exactly what you want
- Format each element of that data into HTML

Here's one way that might look:

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output')

const structureTownData = ([name, {kommunenummer, Menn, Kvinner}]) => ({
  name, 
  kommunenummer, 
  pop: Number(Menn['2018']) + Number(Kvinner['2018'])
})

const formatOutput = ({name, kommunenummer, pop}) => {
  const el = document.createTextNode(`${name} (#${kommunenummer}): ${pop}`)
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  li.appendChild(el);
  output.appendChild(li)
}

fetch("http://wildboy.uib.no/~tpe056/folk/104857.json")
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(({elementer}) => Object.entries(elementer).map(structureTownData))
  .then(towns => towns.forEach(formatOutput))
```

```html
<ul id="output"></ul>

<script>
data = {"elementer":{"Halden":{"kommunenummer":"0101","Menn":{"2016":15306,"2017":15473,"2018":15620},"Kvinner":{"2016":15238,"2017":15317,"2018":15417}},"Oslo kommune":{"kommunenummer":"0301","Menn":{"2016":328424,"2017":332578,"2018":335806},"Kvinner":{"2016":329966,"2017":334181,"2018":337663}}}}


// fake fetch for testing
const fetch = (url) => Promise.resolve(({json: () => data}))
</script>
```

There are plenty of alternative ways to create your HTML.  And you'd have to decide on the exact format you want.  Here I just use an unordered list with elements that look like `Halden (#0101): 31037`.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20135028/5525384

```
const div = document.getElementById('visOversikt');
function makeList(jsonObject, listElement){
    for(var i in jsonObject){
        var newLI = document.createElement('li');
        if  (jsonObject[i] instanceof Array){
            newLI.innerHTML=i;
        }
        else if (jsonObject[i] instanceof Object){
            newLI.innerHTML=i;
        }
        else {
            newLI.innerHTML=i+': '+jsonObject[i];
        }
        listElement.appendChild(newLI)
        if  (jsonObject[i] instanceof Array || jsonObject[i] instanceof Object){
            var newUL = document.createElement('ul');
            listElement.appendChild(newUL);
            makeList(jsonObject[i],newUL);
        }
    }
}
makeList(jsonObject, div);
```