# JSON to unordered list, sorted

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have an xml file that I made a JSON array with objects that are senators with a party, name, and a status of whether they have been voted or not. Only the name needs to be displayed on my HTML list. I don't know how to get it there, though, and I want to sort democrats and republicans dynamically as I go. here is a sample of the array:

```
[{"name":"Chuck Schumer","party":"Democrat","voted":false},
{"name":"Dick Durbin","party":"Democrat","voted":false}, ...]
```

I'm not sure how one does this. I have ID elements set up in my html because I know I need that.

Do I need to JSON.parse first? how do you connect them to the ID values?

Here is my HTML body.

```
     <div id="dropLists" style="display: table">
     <div style="display: table-row">

     <div class="dropList">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Democrats:</legend>
            <ul id="democrats">

            </ul>
        </fieldset>
     </div>

     <div class="dropList">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Republicans:</legend>
            <ul id="republicans">

            </ul>
        </fieldset>
     </div>

     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: The question is quite broad... As far as creating a list from an array, that's answered in [Generate unordered list from JSON Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6692538/215552), among others. Regarding the other questions, it depends on how you're getting the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. Here's an overview:

- `document.querySelector` to select the 2 `ul` elements
- `document.createElement` to create `li` elements
- `element.appendChild` to insert the `li` elements into the `uls element.

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "Chuck Schumer",
    "party": "Democrat",
    "voted": false
  },
  {
    "name": "Dick Durbin",
    "party": "Democrat",
    "voted": false
  },
  {
    "name": "X Y Z",
    "party": "Republican",
    "voted": false
  },
];

data.forEach(({name, party}) => {
  let itemEl = document.createElement('li');
  itemEl.textContent = name;

  let listId = party === 'Democrat' ? '#democrats' : '#republicans';
  let listEl = document.querySelector(listId);
  listEl.appendChild(itemEl);
});
```

```html
<div id="dropLists" style="display: table">
  <div style="display: table-row">

    <div class="dropList">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Democrats:</legend>
        <ul id="democrats">

        </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="dropList">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Republicans:</legend>
        <ul id="republicans">

        </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for including the brief method description. Makes sense to me now,

Answer (score 1):

Filter the list to get either "democrats" or "republicans", map the results to have only the `name` wrapped in a `li` and set the `innerHTML` of the coresponding `ul` ( html elements with `id` will be global variables, so you do `democrats.innerHTML = ...` )

```js
const data = [{"name":"Chuck Schumer","party":"Democrat","voted":false},{"name":"Dick Durbin","party":"Democrat","voted":false},{"name":"Dick Durbin 2","party":"Republican","voted":false}]

democrats.innerHTML = data.filter(o => o.party === "Democrat").map(o => '<li>' + o.name + '</li>').join('');
republicans.innerHTML = data.filter(o => o.party === "Republican").map(o => '<li>' + o.name + '</li>').join('');
```

```html
<div id="dropLists" style="display: table">
  <div style="display: table-row">

    <div class="dropList">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Democrats:</legend>
        <ul id="democrats">

        </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="dropList">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Republicans:</legend>
        <ul id="republicans">

        </ul>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` should be avoided, not only for performance reasons, but also because it is ancient and hard to read. It's like having an API `do('add 3 and 4')` rather than `3 + 4`.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the code getting the data from? Is it reading an XML file? Calling a URL and downloading it? Or are you copying/pasting your array into the code? If you're copying/pasting it, then it's already an array and doesn't need to be JSON.parsed. If it's coming as the entire contents of a file obtained via `fetch`, then you can just use response.json() on the result of the fetch to convert it into an array. Any other source would likely give it to you as a string, in which case you just need to call JSON.parse() on the string to get the array.

Once you have an array, it's extremely easy to split it into two lists, one for each party:

```
const dems = senators.filter(senator => senator.party === 'Democrat');
const reps = senators.filter(senator => senator.party === 'Republican');
```

And then to convert them to an HTML list inside your existing ul elements:

```
const demList = document.getElementById('democrats');
dems.forEach(dem => {
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    listItem.textContent = dem.name;
    demList.appendChild(listItem);
});
```

(The code is similar for the Republican list.)

Comment: Actually, scratch that, @juvnar provided a better solution :P